# If someone asked, and if I do t understand its soution, then, how do i understand? Do I not have aright to ask again?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

First of all,

I searched the question, and someone asked, I found its solution. But I think, that solution is not clear enough. Forvexample, there, the reason why the integral is zero is not explained. So I dont understand that solution. Therefore, I am asking again. sorry for [dublicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453437/show-that-f-is-integrable-and-int-i-f-0)

(Please dont downvote my question because of dublicate :)I just want to learn properly.

[image]

Please explain more clear. Thank you so much:)

Comment: You shall recall the definition of being integrable through the upper and the lower Darboux integral sums. Over such simple function as in your case, you can compute both sums as the linked answer suggests - is there anything unclear so far?

Comment: I said that this question is asked and I posted its link. Need not to say again! @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I know the definition. But I dont understand how to apply this definition. Please can you write its solution clearly and step by step.? I am a student. And I have an exam tommorow. I Want to go to the exam by learning such types question.  Please:) thank you thank you:) @Ilya

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or to clarify what you don't understand and still need help with. Many questions get more than one answer. Don't accept the first answer which comes along straight away. Leave comments to help people who read your question later to give more helpful answers, or to allow the first person to edit their answer to be more helpful. Have patience.

Comment: But I dont know who the same question is asked. How do I want more helpful? It got only one answer,which is unclear. Also, the user answered that question also helped me for previous my questions. Honestly I dont understand the user's style to solve a question. Thus I dont want to ask a hep to the user, sorry but honestly that is all. @markBennet now, because this my question is closed, nobody cannot answer. I stated everything honestly above, also sent its link. I am so sorry. I am too desperate. :(

Comment: @B11b You have enough reputation to post a comment on that other question. It seems that most of your function is zero, and all you have to do is to contain your one point in as small a part of the sum as you choose.

Comment: Well, Dear @MarkBennet can you post its solution more clearly, understadable on Bstr's (another user's) question. ? Please make such a kindness:) I will upvote your solution for thanks, I promise :) please, I need and want to learn. Thank you:)